# HERE Javascript API bug?: gesture zoom not centered properly

Tags: here-api

It appears to me that if the map container is placed anywhere but the top left corner of the page, pinch zoom is no longer centered properly. I have encountered this problem on iPad 2 (Safari 5.1), iPhone 5 (Safari 7.0), Sony Xperia tablet Z (Chrome 34.0).

If i have missed something obvious as comes to forcing this thing into expected behavior, I would be delighted to have this pointed out to me. Otherwise I'm inclined to call this a Here bug.

This simple fiddle replicates the issue when used with a touch screen device
http://jsfiddle.net/Thernys/E97rn/

And since apparently code is required with a fiddle link, I replicate the relevant parts of the super simple example.

HTML

```
<body>
    <!-- add a number of <br/> if you like -->
    <div id='mapContainer'></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#mapContainer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

JS

```
var nMap = new nokia.maps.map.Display(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'), {
        zoomLevel: 10,
        center: [52.51, 13.4],
        components: [
            new nokia.maps.map.component.panning.Drag(),
            new nokia.maps.map.component.zoom.Gesture()
        ],
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this exactly same issue. After some research I realized that it's occurring because the map container wasn't placed in the cartesian origin of the document (top: 0, left:0). I don't know if this is a bug of the API or if there's any configuration that fixes it.

The workaround I found out was to create the map inside an iframe element and make sure it occupies the entire width.